# Trouble with input shape of Embedding layer in Keras

Tags: python, keras, artificial-intelligence, lstm

I am new at modeling in Keras Python. I wanted to create a model that will generate text answer to my messages like chatbot. I read that I need to use tokenizer and to_categorical method. There is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Input, Dropout, Embedding
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer, text_to_word_sequence
from keras.utils import pad_sequences, to_categorical


X = ["Hello!", "Greetings!"]

tokenizer = Tokenizer(1000)

X_seq = pad_sequences(tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X), 20)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Embedding(1000, 100, input_length=20))
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dense(1000, "softmax"))

model.summary()

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X_seq, to_categorical(X_seq), epochs=10, batch_size=20)

print(model.predict(pad_sequences(tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(["Greetings!"]), 20)))
```

value **1000** is max count of unique words in tokenizer vocabulary
**X** is my input list of messages.
**20** is max length of text.
I wanted to create self-learning model but I don't really inderstand how to do it. In internet I found that I need to pass same input and output values but my model should return something like that [0.1,0.2,0.3....] - the max value represents the word which model predicted. But when I try to fit that it raises exception:

```
ValueError: Shapes (None, 20) and (None, 1000) are incompatible
```

I guess that it is a trouble with shapes of input list and embedding layer. Guys please help me deal with that. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In this particular example using `to_categorical(X_seq)` gives you targets having `[num_of_samples, 20]` shape. It means that if you use this target variable to fit model it will expect that number of classes will equal 20 (model output shape = `(None, 20)`). So to fix your example I would suggest you change `model.add(Dense(1000, "softmax"))` to `model.add(Dense(20, "softmax"))`.

Additionaly before using `tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X)` I would suggest you to fit tokenizer using `tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X)`.

Comment: So trouble was with output model data not input?

Comment: I will check your suggestion now

Comment: Unfortunately your suggestion does not help. Program just raised new exception:
`ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 20 for '{{node Squeeze}} = Squeeze[T=DT_FLOAT, squeeze_dims=[-1]](remove_squeezable_dimensions/Squeeze)' with input shapes: [?,20].`